# How can I get an instagram business account with Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

- The condition I am using:
  Graph API version: 7.0
- The problem I have: I can get the Instagram business account of my Facebook developer account,
  However, I cannot get the Instagram business account when I login Facebook with another account.
  The account has the permissions below:

  1. The Instagram account is connected to its Facebook page.
  2. The Instagram account is a business profile.
  3. The Facebook account that I want to connect to Instagram account has the authorisation more than editor.
- I could get this: 
  `/me?fields=name,picture`, but not 
  `/me/accounts?fields=instagram_business_account`

I tried with this API: 
`/me/accounts?fields=instagram_business_account{name,username,profile_picture_url},access_token,name,picture{url}', function(response) { }`
The response I got: 
`{ "data": [ ] }`

Do I need additional authorisation or something?

Comment: What permissions did you ask from the user, and have you _verified_ they actually granted them?

Comment: the user is not a business account, but it has the authorisation more than editor. The rest permissions are default.

Comment: I am not talking about their role on any pages, I am talking about the _permissions_ your app requested when they logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Your App is most likely not public and and you need to go through the review process first - with all the permissions you need. Else, it will only work for users with a role in the App.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

Also, the IG account must be a business account, and it must be connected to the Facebook Page: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/898752960195806

Comment: My app went through app review and that has been approved.

Comment: are you sure you authorized the additional user correctly, with the neccessary permissions? maybe you authorized the permissions in the graph api explorer for testing, with your app admin account? or maybe the IG account is not connected to the fb page?

Comment: actually the user's account isn't business authorised, but there was no statement that the facebook account should be business account to get facebook page..the user is connected to IG account.

Comment: the IG account must be a business account, and it must be connected to the facebook page. i added that info to my answer.

Comment: Is there a rule that the facebook account should be verified as a business account?

Answer (score 0):

To get Instagram IDs linked to user's pages you need these permissions (verified and approved for your app): `instagram_basic`, `pages_show_list`, `pages_read_engagement`.
You can read guide here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started
Everything is correct on that page except extra permission needed to get IG ID: `pages_read_engagement`